# Problem with update_user_meta() meta_value

Tags: users, user-meta

I am trying to insert a large number of user in to the wordpress db using wp_insert_user(). After inserting each user, I am trying to add an user meta for each user. I am doing like this:

```
$meta_value = //data from an API (e.g.: 19, 34, 1290 etc)
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $new_user_data );// it works fine
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_meta_key', $meta_value ); //does not work
```

When I run it, user get inserted, but not the meta.
When I try like below, it works:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $new_user_data );// it works fine
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_meta_key', '1290' ); //it works
```

I have over 1000 users, I need to insert, so I need to insert the meta dynamically as well. Any idea how can I overcome this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump( $meta_value );` ?

Comment: Anyway, I fixed it. Leaving the solution as answer, if anyone else face similar problem, it will help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it doing like below:

```
$meta_value = //data from an API (e.g.: 19, 34, 1290 etc)
$meta_value_string = "". $meta_value;
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $new_user_data );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_meta_key', $meta_value_string );
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: For one: Note the existence of [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [`strval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) in PHP. For another, that ought not be necessary anyway: the `$meta_value` parameter of `update_user_meta()` can even be assigned an object or array, which will be serialized before being written to the database. It will accept an integer just fine. The error *must* have been elsewhere.